# Differences in ARP scanning macOS / Raspbian / Python results

Tags: python, scapy, arp

With the help of some tutorials I wrote a Python script that lists network details of the devices in the network.

I however only detect certain devices if I run the Python script. I already saw when searching that certain devices (e.g. iOS devices) don't respond (but are occasionally detected), but the strange thing is:

- macOS (Catalina, 10.15.2) does find these devices with "arp -a"
- Raspbian (10, buster) also finds a number of devices when doing "arp -a" but does not find the iOS devices
- Python (3/2.7) does not find the Arduino devices which Raspbian and macOS do find, I run the Python script from the mac.
- Running the Python script on the Pi does give me the Arduino devices as well.

I use Scapy for the ARP messages in Python (based on this tutorial: https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/building-network-scanner-using-scapy):

```
def find_devices(gateway):
    _ip_items = gateway.split(".")
    target_ip = "%s.%s.%s.%s" % (_ip_items[0], _ip_items[1], _ip_items[2], "0/24")


    # IP Address for the destination
    # create ARP packet
    arp = ARP(pdst=target_ip)
    # create the Ether broadcast packet
    # ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff MAC address indicates broadcasting
    ether = Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")

    # stack them
    packet = ether/arp
    result = srp(packet, timeout=3, verbose=0)[0]

    # a list of clients, we will fill this in the upcoming loop
    clients = []

    for sent, received in result:
        # for each response, append ip and mac address to `clients` list
        clients.append({'ip': received.psrc, 'mac': received.hwsrc})
        print("{:16}    {}".format(received.psrc, received.hwsrc))
```

Of course I could use ARP -A directly (e.g. execute that from Python and parse the results), but I am much more curious about the reasons that the Raspberry Pi seems to detect more devices than the Python code and macOS detects even more (are they cheating and using bonjour e.g.?) but how come both detect the Arduino's (Nano 33 IoT boards with MQTT pub/sub code on them) while the script on macOS does not detect those.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out that I can get even the iOS devices and Arduino devices when I chance the timeout to a much larger value (e.g. 15). It is still much more slow than macOS (arp -a gives an instant response) but they probably draw it from some cache or something(?). It does produce all devices that I see in arp -a also from the Python code even though it then becomes really slow.

Comment: `arp -a` is fully from cache. some devices do not answer to gratuitous ARP, in the case of iPhones it's not documented but likely either for security measures, or to spare battery. You might want to try passive scanning (sniffing everything and detecting ARP requests sent as devices join), in addition to what you're already doing. Or use the Bonjour protocol to see Apple devices specifically